# PHP Looped array returning only last entry

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to turn a series of arrays into a serialized entry.

My array looks like this:

```
array ( 0 => 'Crystal', 1 => 'Crystal@gmail.com', )
array ( 0 => 'Tyler', 1 => 'Tyler@gmail.com', )
array ( 0 => 'Richard', 1 => 'Richard@gmail.com', )
```

Here is my code that is breaking them down for re-entry:

```
foreach ($match[1] as $key => $value) {

  if ($key == '0') {
    $just_invited['name'] = $value;         
  }

  if ($key == '1') {
    $just_invited['email'] = $value;
  }

  add_user_meta( $athlete->ID, 'fans_invited', $just_invited);
}
```

I can get the `$just_invited['$keys']` to echo properly, but when I try to `add_user_meta` only adds the last iteration.

Comment: Your array(s) have issues. Is that supposed to be one array with three arrays in it, or do you just have three arrays with extra commas? Why are you declaring keys `0` and `1` when those would be the keys by default?

Comment: Because I just started using arrays and serialized data. The arrays are the result of pulling the names and emails from strings that contained div elements. Defining the keys worked for when I was just trying to print the data to make sure I could single out the entries.

Comment: Here is what I mean. http://pastebin.com/MaVUhM6w That has the syntax errors corrected. The keys are still `0` and `1` - there's no need to write them in. Now, I still don't understand your question.

Comment: m59 is right. Your array doesn't make any sense. You have 3 of them and the keys are the same. Don't you find that odd?

Comment: @Machavity I don't quite get what you mean. If they were numerical arrays, that's what the keys would be anyway. Technically, they ought to be associative, where the key names are `name` and `email`.

Comment: You should use literal comparison, `===`, and stick with numbers if your array keys are numeric. But really, we need to see more code to help you. What is `$match[1]`?.

Comment: @m59 I guess I'm just missing the rest of the array. I feel like there's some information not being provided

Comment: I was afraid that adding the code where I got the array from would be more complicating than helping. They're a series of arrays that have 2 entries each. I didn't number them, that's just how they came out of the var_extract.